# Windows 7/8/10: Global user session for multiple users

Tags: windows, session, active-directory, user-profile

Currently, I have one PC operated by 5 individuals. 
These individuals all log in using the same username and password so that they  can share a desktop and any open applications. Security-wise, this is no good. I cannot track each users activities.

I would like to find out if it is possible to have any of those 5 users log in and have it resume the session, but with the knowledge of who was logged in.

For a better explanation:

**Current scenario**

- User A logs on to profile A, or resumes session A.
- User B logs on to profile B, or resumes session B.
- User C logs on to profile C, or resumes session C.

If user A has a file open, user B cannot access or modify it, and neither can user C.

User A would have to log in and close the file and applications so that user B or C can use them. 
In some instances, User A is not available and the others have to wait for him/her to return to close it. This is impractical.

Additionally, User A would have application Q open which each user uses. This means 3 instances of the same application will be running on each of the sessions consuming more resources than needed.

**What I would like is:**

- User A logs on to profile Z, or resumes session Z.
- User B logs on to
  profile Z, or resumes session Z.
- User C logs on to profile Z, or
  resumes session Z.

Profile Z and all users belong to a common group (for permissions).

- User A logs on, locks the screen with application running.
- User B logs on, resumes session with application running from user A.

Comment: If this is what you want, then wouldn't it be better to give each user their own login and password, but creating a Shared folder in which all users have access (read and write permissions) to?

Comment: The problem is that files in use have to be closed by other users, or applications which can only be used by a single user must also be closed. If the user with the file open is out of the office, there's no way to close the file short of restarting the PC. This is by no means an option for us.

Comment: You would need to build your own credential provider.  [pGina](http://pgina.org/index.html) might simplify this, although I've never tried it myself.